# emacs archive-mode rar files

Tags: dired, archive-mode

While the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Archives.html) states that archive mode supports `rar` files, I seem to have no luck with it. Trying to view/open a `rar` file in `dired`, lead to this message:

```
File mode specification error: (file-error Searching for program No such file or directory lsar)
```

My emacs version is 25.2.1. I suspect the source of the error is here, in using `unar` instead of `unrar`:

```
(defun archive-rar-extract (archive name)
  ;; unrar-free seems to have no way to extract to stdout or even to a file.
  (if (file-name-absolute-p name)
      ;; The code below assumes the name is relative and may do undesirable
      ;; things otherwise.
      (error "Can't extract files with non-relative names")
    (archive-extract-by-file archive name `("unar" "-no-directory" "-o") "Successfully extracted")))
```

I don't have experience modifying compiled emacs lisp libraries. Would love to know what is causing this error.

Comment: Yep, that looks like a bug to me.  I would report it to the Emacs team, and try fixing it yourself in the meantime.  You can require the library `(require 'arc-mode)` and then use the same function name and everything, while just changing the program name.  In my own setup, I actually substituted it with an absolute path to a registered version of `unrar` which required modifying some of the regexp functions since the output was slightly different.  My recollection is that `arc-mode` was based on the assumption everyone would be using an unrar free version, which was not available to me.

Answer (score 2):

On Arch Linux, installing [`unarchiver`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/unarchiver/) from the AUR solved the problem. The programs `unar` and `lsar` are provided by the said package from the AUR.